# C# generic compare method [analogue of C++ template]

Tags: c#, c++, icomparable, generic-method

Both C++ and C# support generics. However, I don't see any way to rewrite a simple C++ function template that compares any two args (arg1 > arg2 ?) into a singe C# generic method:
**C++**

```
template<typename T>
int compare(const T & st1, const T & st2) {
    if (std::less<T>() (st1, st2)) 
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

works both with `int`, `std::string`, `std::vector`etc.

```
compare(33, 4);         // 1

std::vector<int> v1{ 1,0 }, v2{ 1,0,0 };
compare(v1, v2);        // -1

std::vector<std::string> vs1{ "hi", "bob" }, vs2{ "hi", "ben" };
compare(vs1, vs2);      // 1
```

**C#**

```
   class Demo
    {
        public static int Compare<T>(T v1, T v2) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            if (v1.CompareTo(v2) < 0)
                return -1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

doesn't work with, say C# `Lists<>`:

```
List<int> v1 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> v2 = new List<int> { 3, 4 };
Console.WriteLine($"Compare(v1, v2): {Compare(v1, v2)}");
```

***error***: no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.IComparable>'
Is the only way to make it work with both integral types and collections in C# to overload each time?

```
public static int Compare<T>(List<T> v1, List<T> v2) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (v1[i].CompareTo(v2[i]) < 0)
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `List<int>` *doesn't implement* `IComparable<List<int>>`: you can compare items (which are `int`) but not collections - `List<int>` by default

Comment: Do you want to compare the reference? or the items?

Comment: I don't know any c++, but can you explain how does vectors in C++ know how they are compared? Or how does the `less` function know how to compare things?

Comment: "Both C++ and C# support generics." - Well, C++ supports templates, and C# supports generics. They are different ways of accomplishing many of the same goals, but they're not the same. (C++/CLI presumably supports generics as well, and it's possible that standard C++ does as well now, but here you appear to be using just C++ templates.) [This MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/generics-and-templates-visual-cpp) is probably useful to you.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, if I new how to implement `compare` method without `IComparable`, I would do it

Comment: @J.vanLangen, I'd like to compare items in this case, but you are most welcome to show both options here

Comment: @Sweeper in C++ `std::less` typically uses `operator <`, and this operator compares `std::vector`s lexicographically. Compare operators are explicilty defined for most of standard containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that `List<int>` doesn't implement `IComparer<List<int>>` and this fact doesn't meet method's specification:

```
public static int Compare<T>(T v1, T v2) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Since `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`.

I suggest something like this (quick and in some case a dirty solution):

```
public static int Compare<T>(T v1, T v2, IComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  if (null == comparer)              // If we don't have tailored comparer
    comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;  // Try default one

  // If we don't know how to compare - throw exception
  if (null == comparer)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer", 
      $"Type {typeof(T).Name} doesn't have default comparer; comparer must not be null.");

  // Taken from the question: 
  // if (v1.CompareTo(v2) < 0)
  //          return -1;
  //      return 1;
  // You, probably, may want just  
  // return comparer.Compare(v1, v2);
  return comparer.Compare(v1, v2) < 0 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

So you can put, in a simple case

```
int result = Compare(15, 25); // Comparer<int>.Default will be used
```

In a complex case with no default comparer you have to implement it:

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
  public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return 0;
    else if (null == x)
      return -1;
    else if (null == y)
      return 1;

    Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    using (var en_x = x.GetEnumerator()) {
      using (var en_y = y.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!en_x.MoveNext()) 
          if (!en_y.MoveNext())
            return 0;
          else
            return 1;
        else if (en_y.MoveNext())
          return -1;

        if (comparer != null) {
          int result = comparer.Compare(en_x.Current, en_y.Current);

          if (result != 0)
            return result;
        }
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

And provide the comparer

```
List<int> v1 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
List<int> v2 = new List<int> { 3, 4 };

int another result = Compare(v1, v2, new MyComparer<int>());
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just a short question (nothing important): I’ve never seen `if (null == obj)` being used anywhere before, why do you use it that way? Does it provide any benefits? For it doesn’t benefit readability and afaik doesn’t give performance benefits, or does it?

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow: `if (null == obj)` syntax instead of `if (obj == null)` came from C language: if you (occasionaly) skip one `=` then `if (null = obj)` will be easy to detect *compile time error*; when `if (obj = null)` means "assign `null` to `obj`, then convert `obj` to `bool` and perform `if`" which often is by far harder to detect

Comment: The line `return comparer.Compare(v1, v2) < 0 ? -1 : 1;`. So it can't be equal? Why not `return comparer.Compare(v1, v2);`?

Comment: @J. van Langen: THank you! My line - `comparer.Compare(v1, v2) < 0 ? -1 : 1;` is a simplified version of `if (v1.CompareTo(v2) < 0) return -1; return 1;` from the question; I've added the comment with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare for equality, you can use [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx) since you cannot compare generic types with `==` (apart from `== null`).

```
/// <returns>
///     <see langword="true" /> if <paramref name="v1" /> is equal to <paramref name="v2" />; otherwise, <see langword="false" />.
/// </returns>
public static bool Compare<T>(T v1, T v2)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(v1 , v2);
}
```

You may need to elaborate a bit more on what you want to compare, because some concepts (e.g. *greater than*, *less than*, *items count* etc.) don't make sense for any arbitrary `T`.

---

## EDIT:

Seems like you want to compare the items of collections. It doesn't make sense do not restrict `T` to be an `IEnumerable` then.

You could make use of [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare whether to collections contain the same items, and you can even specify a comparer for each item.

Comment: in this case I'd like element-wise comparison, being less than or greater than for numeric types and ordering alphabetically chars. Code snippets are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined T to be of Type IComparable ( or a descendant from it) when you wrote:

```
   where T : IComparable<T>
```

and in your example you used int as a type for you list which is not of type IComparable , so the conversion error is thrown.